# Does Liferay 6.1.1 support Java 1.7

Tags: liferay, java-7

I am using Liferay with Tomcat bundle of version 6.1.1 with Java 1.7.

When I try to deploy my project on Liferay it gives the error "Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported."

Does Liferay 6.1.1 not support Java version 1.7?

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "supported": Liferay should run well on Java7, but needs to hold on to Java6 for quite a while as minimum requirement due to many app servers (that are still supported by their vendors as well we Liferay) still demanding this version. Thus there's no aggressive use of the new features in Java7, despite Oracle-Java6 being out-of-public-maintenance already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay 6.1 EE (Enterprise version) supports Java 1.7. Liferay 6.2 which will be the next major release of Liferay will have Java 1.7 support for Community as well as Enterprise Edition.

Current stable Community Edition of Liferay does not support Java 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running liferay 6.1 community edition in tomcat 7 with JDK 7 without any issue.
I have tried following things :

1. Create a custom portal layout
2. create a custom portal theme
3. use custom/facebook authentication
4. responsiveness of UI using bootstrap
5. simple liferay mvc portlets
6. database (postgres) persistence

   All of the above worked without any issue. Let me know what are the areas from liferay you are using. I might give it a try

Comment: I just downloaded the liferay 6.1.1 with tomcat bundle and try to deploy the java project which was made using java 1.7.While adding the project into the server it gives error "Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported".

Answer (score 0):

start the server with java 1.7(change the jvm in setenv.bat or setenv.sh).